# Mat-card is not specifying gap below and above the row

Tags: css, angular, angular-flex-layout, mat-card

I am trying to specify some gap between two rows while displaying mat cards. But it is not showing properly after using flex.

[image: card flex]

**This is the HTML file:-**

```
<div fxLayout="row wrap" fxLayoutAlign="space-around">
  <mat-card class="list-card" *ngFor="let uri of urlData" fxLayoutGap="20px">
    <mat-card-header>
      <mat-card-title>{{uri.title}}</mat-card-title>
      <mat-card-subtitle>3 weeks ago</mat-card-subtitle>
    </mat-card-header>
    <img mat-card-image src="https://uU0bbBPEJvIK7H7f4qaSuQ.jpeg(58 kB)
https://uU0bbBPEJvIK7H7f4qaSuQ.jpeg
" alt="img alt title">
    <mat-card-content>
      <a href="https://medium.....64" class="mat-caption">
        {{uri.documentURL}} </a>
      <!-- <section> -->
      <mat-chip-list>
        <mat-chip>Angular</mat-chip>
      </mat-chip-list>
      <!-- </section> -->
      <p>
        {{uri.description}}
      </p>
    </mat-card-content>
    <mat-card-actions>
      <mat-icon>share_outline</mat-icon>
      <mat-icon>bookmark_outline</mat-icon>
    </mat-card-actions>
  </mat-card>
</div>
```

**This is the css:-**

```
.list-card{
    max-width: 260px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two options to do that

1: Use `flexLayoutGap` as you had done for `row` gap, but you need to customize your structure as mention [here](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/wiki/fxLayoutGap-API) 
*for bottom gap you need to use `flex column` as well.*

2: Use `margin-bottom` on your card class `.list-card`

```
.list-card{
   margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks let me try

Comment: @NoobCoder when using `fxLayoutGap` you cant aling item in middle for that you need to remove that and use `fxFlex` instead so that they take space according to the view-port width. you can alos use `fxFlex=30` for percent or 'fxFlex=30px' in pixels  [Reference](https://tburleson-layouts-demos.firebaseapp.com/#/docs)

Answer (score 0):

`.list-card{
   max-width: 260px;
   margin: 10px;
}`

try this code

Comment: I don't want to use margin. Padding will help ? let me check

Comment: Padding can not use in this case